# Does Google Sheet API has Spreadsheet Metadate Update option? Trying to update Google Spreadsheet name but can't find it

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-sheets-api

On the Google Sheet API Documentation, I see you can update Sheet name but not the Spreadsheet name. Does anyone know if it is possible to rename a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to change the Spreadsheet name.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

You can change the Spreadsheet name using Sheets API. When the Spreadsheet name is changed, the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate of Sheets API is used. The endpoint and request body are as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body:

```
{
 "requests": [
  {
   "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
    "properties": {
     "title": "### please set the Spreadsheet name ###"
    },
    "fields": "title"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

#### Note:

- Also you can change the Spreadsheet name using the method of [Files: update Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatespreadsheetpropertiesrequest)
- [SpreadsheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SpreadsheetProperties)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Jie Jenn Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.